# Registering JavaScript code in server control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need some help with jQuery. At the moment I am building my server control that has div in it. Inside that div there is an iFrame. I want to be able to resize my div with jQuery. I have accomplished this through simple samples.

As I've said, I'm building a server control so I cannot add jQuery manually on every page. It should be automated in a way that when I drag drop my control on designer surface I don't have to worry about resizing the Div.

Currently I am registering all the relevant *.js files in master page. I have a child page wich inherits master page. On that page I have my control. I cannot make a *.js file and register it as I can have multiple instances of same control.

Where do I register my script block? How is it done?

Any clarification on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this server control or .Ascx Server control?  If it is a server control, what type of control does it inherit from?  If you inherit from a WebControl, you can do something like this (this is an abbreviated example, so will require some work on your side):

```
Public Class myControl
    Inherits WebControl

       Private Sub attachWebResources()

        Dim styleLink As String = "<link rel='stylesheet' text='text/css' href='{0}' />"
        Dim location As String = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.[GetType](), "myApp.WebControls.myStyles.css")
        Dim styleInclude As New LiteralControl([String].Format(styleLink, location))
        DirectCast(Page.Header, HtmlControls.HtmlHead).Controls.Add(styleInclude)

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Me, Me.GetType, "myApp.WebControls.jquery-1.4.1.min.js")


        EnsureChildControls()

    End Sub


       Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        attachWebResources()
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This example shows how to included an embedded CSS and JS file in your control.  You will need to include the JS and CSS file in your Web Control Library project.  You will then need to add a reference for your JS file in your AssemblyInfo.Vb file, like this:

```
<Assembly: Web.UI.WebResource("myApp.WebControls.jquery-1.4.1.min.js", "text/javascript")>
```

If this is an ASCX web control, or any kind of server control, you can add the code like this:

```
    Dim myScript As New StringBuilder
    myScript.Append("function helloWorld(){" & vbCrLf)
    myScript.Append("alert('hello world')" & vbCrLf)
    myScript.Append("}" & vbCrLf)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myKey", myScript.tostring, True)
```

Either way, if you have more questions let me know which type you are using and post the relevant code that you have added so far.

Comment: Hmmm, I get what you are writing and I have already done that for JS functions. My problem is jQuery code. It goes like this - $(document).ready(function () {$('#myControl').draggable();}); - this code needs to be written dynamically somewhere. Where and how? For that to be a part of JS file I would have to make the whole file, write it to disc, register it as resource and that register it as script. Is it advised to be done like that? I'm kind of lost here as I'm pretty new with jQuery.

Comment: I don't see why this would be a problem.  I've used this method (the first example) with JQuery.  After all, jQuery is just javascript.  Of course, you will need to include the various jQuery libraries you would use.  Chances are though, your project will already have them included.  You have two options, include those libraries as I suggested in the first example (and you can also add your own JS file this way) or make the user of your control include them in their application (which I don't think is unreasonable).  I'm not exactly sure what your concern is, though.